# MEAN.JS New Controller Function and Route

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, meanjs

I'm learning MEAN.JS and having a few issues with routing, just looking to add a new function to the articles project called getSubArticles which calls to the server and does something.

```
    //articles.server.routes.js
    app.route('/articles/:articleId/subarticles')
            .get(articles.read);

    //articles.server.controller.js
    exports.read = function(req, res) {
        res.jsonp("My Sub articles");//just using for testing
    };

    //articles.client.controller.js
    $scope.getSubArticles = function() {
                // What goes here as everything I've tried has failed, but the route could be constructed incorrectly
            };

//articles.client.view.html
    <section id="subarticle-listing" data-ng-controller="ArticlesController" data-ng-init="getSubArticles()">
```

Any ideas where I'm going wrong? Got a sample MEAN.JS project with non default routes/functions I can look at...

Cheers,
Adrian

Answer (score 1):

A few things jump out, first you should make sure your route is getting hit when requested, you can add a console.log in your read funciton. In your app.js (or server.js, whichever file is used to start your app) you need to have:

```
 //server.js file:
    var router = express.Router();    
    var routes = require('./articles.server.routes.js'); //path to your routes file
    router.use('/',routes);
```

In your articles.server.routes.js file, include these requires at the top, and your route can't have a variable then a fixed name afterwards, basically anything after the variable will get chopped off, so the new route should be:

```
// articles.server.routes.js
var express = require('express'),
    app = express().Router();

 app.route('/articles/subarticles/:articleId')
                .get(articles.read);
```

In your articles.server.controller.js:

```
 exports.read = function(req, res) {
        var articleid = req.params.bid
        console.log('read function called' + articleid)
        res.jsonp("My Sub articles");//just using for testing
    };
```

Now in your Angular controller:

```
$scope.getSubArticles = function() {
    $http.get('/articles/subarticles/' + $scope.articleId)

    .success(function(data){
        //do something with your return data
    }
    .error(function(err){
        //error handler
}
}
```

Hope that helps, if not, let me know and I can suggest a few more things.

Comment: Hey Eric, That did help and worked perfectly thanks

You wouldnt know the issue here would you?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31570779/mean-js-remove-template-layout-and-render-json-at-a-route